# Scala Either with Unit

Tags: scala

I am curious about the proper way of doing this. Suppose I want to signal success or failure from a method. Is this acceptable, if there is nothing I want to say in case of success, other than it succeeded?

```
def fn(): Either[Throwable, Unit]
```

And what is the proper way to return a Right() from this method, as a success? Apparently just returning Right() gives a deprecation warning (Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated).

I can also probably do Option[Throwable], but that doesn't keep with the spirit of how I read Option. Or maybe return the result of scala.util.Try and evaluate Success/Failure?

--
On the deprecation warning, just FYI.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> def fn:Either[Throwable, Unit] = { Right() }
<console>:11: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: Right.apply[A, B](b: B): scala.util.Right[A,B]
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: Right((): Unit)
       def fn:Either[Throwable, Unit] = { Right() }
                                               ^
fn: Either[Throwable,Unit]
```

Comment: I think `Try[T]` makes complete sense in this case.

Comment: But Try moves the error handling/recovery to the caller. I'd prefer to keep it in the callee if the callee can recover, and return a failure only if it cannot recover. So they are not exactly equivalent.

Comment: in general if you have Unit there like this `Either[T, Unit]` it means you probably should consider using `Option[T]` instead of `Either`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it depends on the kind of API that you are looking for.

`def fn(): Either[Throwable, Unit]` sounds pretty non-idiomatic to me. If the main result you expect of the function is a side effect, then there doesn't seem to be a use in using an `Either`. Did this come up because it's the terminal operation of a monadic operation chain?

It's become less popular and less idiomatic these days, but I would probably go with a `Try[A]` and handle the cases there. The other idiomatic choice would be to, rather than shuffle exceptions in your `Either`, to create a sealed trait hierarchy of all your error kinds and return those from your effectful function rather than raw `Throwable` instances.

I'm not seeing the error you note when calling `Right()` or `Right( () )` at the REPL, what version of `scalac` are you using?

Comment: `Right()` warns in 2.11.8 at least. Do you mean `Try[Unit]` is less popular? or `Try[Anything]`? I have read people not liking Try. Like the OP, I have balked at `Try[Unit]`, but `Option[Throwable]` piques my interest, is this evil: `Try(???).recover { case e => e }.toOption`

Comment: @som-snytt But how do you reason about the error msg logging?

Comment: I added the deprecation warning in the original post. And yes, my hesitation with Try() is that a lot of people seem to not be very fond of it. I don't claim I understand why, it may be some math somewhere that proves them right.,  Also just to list my original use case, I am wrapping an event creation which may throw an exception during construction (due to Java API use) but otherwise doesn't return anything interesting.

Comment: so as the original question pointed out, I would like to write a `validate` method which check some conditions and return a list of exceptions if an error occurred or Unit otherwise, hence `validate(...) : Either[List[Exception], Unit]`. Is there more idiomatic way to write such a method?

Comment: @abiratsis you probably want to look into something like the [Validated type](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) from the Cats library.
Short answer, the Either type is for dependent computations, the Validated type is for independent computations. If your validations do not depend on each others, you're better off with the Validated type.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Unit` as type and return `()`.

```
def fn(): Either[Throwable, Unit] = Right(())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return `Option[T]`. `Either[T, Unit]` doesn't contain any more data than `Option[T]` and if `T` is some error type in your domain then it's also pretty readable and easy to understand (`Throwable`  is a bit suspicious to me but that is a discussion of its own)

```scala
def fn(): Option[Throwable] = ???
```

Reading the above type as: `Some(e)` means there is an error, `None` means there was no error.